# automatic newline printed in C

Tags: c, arrays, newline

Here's my code:

```
void fun1(char data[2][10]);//function prototype
int i, j; char data[2][11];//variables
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)//populating the 2D array of chars
{               
    for (j = 0; j < 11; j++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &data[i][j]);
    }
}

fun1(data);

void fun1(char data[2][10])//function to print the array out
{
    int i, j, sum;
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 11; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", data[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my inputs and outputs:

```
(inputs)

aaabbbccce  
aaabbbccce

(outputs)

aaabbbccce

aaabbbccce
```

My question is why is there a newline in the output when i haven't specified one?
By the way, is it ok if my function parameters dont match the size of my array? Like my array is char data[2][11] and the parameter i passed in is char data[2][10].

Comment: When you gave it your input did you perchance press the Enter key after you typed `aaabbbccce`?

Comment: yes i typed: aaabbbccce (enter) aaabbbccce (enter)

Comment: When you type "enter" you specified a newline. Enter = newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Change all those '11' to '10'

   You declareed `fun1()` as `void fun1(char data[][10])`, but gave it an argument of type `char [][11]`.
2. Change `scanf("%c", ...)` to `scanf(" %c", ...)`

   The space before `%` will ignore the blank characters, such as newline, in your input.

   Your input

   ```
   aaabbbccce(enter)
   aaabbbccce(enter)
   ```

   includes 22 characters, not 21 ones. The (enter) after the first 'e' should be ignored.

   If you use `scanf("%c", ...)` to read the input, you should give an input like

   ```
   aaabbbccceaaabbbccce(enter)
   ```

   to your program.

Answer (score 0):

You should correct the loop limits from 11 to 10.
You should do it in both the functions. But doing it in fun1() should suffice.

Comment: ok i tried this and it prints out aaabbbccce aaabbbccc the last 'e' is missing

Comment: Add a printf("\n") after the nested loop of j variable, inside the loop of i-variable in the fun1().
That should do.

Did you change the limits in both the functions?

Comment: Yes i changed it in fun1 and when populating the array

Comment: Can you tell how exactly you are providing the input?

Comment: i typed "aaabbbccce" pressed enter then typed "aaabbbccce" then pressed enter. I changed the loop limits, it solved the newline problem but now it doesnt print the last 'e' in the second line

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's ok if your function parameters don't match the array size, at least you wouldn't get what you want.
As we know, when you use array as a parameter, in fact calling function passes its array's first address(aka the variable name of array) to the called function, and called function receives the first address as its parameter's address, so both the parameters share the same memory.
C allows this, but you might see the warning messages.